# How to find a particular pattern?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Hi I have to find a pattern in Javascript where each letter present must be preceded and followed by + sign.
Is there a way to achieve that using regex?
Suppose if my string is ++3+4++3+ , it is true
whereas if my string is 3+4++3+, it is false

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
/^(\++\d+(?=\+))+\++$/
```

**Code:**

```
var re = /^(\++\d+(?=\+))+\++$/;
var s1 = '++3+4++3+'
var s2 = '3+4++3+'

re.test(s1);
true

re.test(s2);
false
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/kO1pA3/1)

Answer (score 1):

((+)+[0-9])+(++)

This says (match one or more of +, match one [0-9]) one or more times, match at least one + at the end of the string

++3+4++3+ == true

3+4++3+ == false

This site saves many hours of regex suffering: http://www.regexr.com/

JS:

```
var str = "++3+4++3+";
var patt = /((\+)+[0-9])+(\++)/;
var result = patt.test(str);
```

Comment: You need to anchor your regex.

Comment: This will check it there's one number preceded and followed by a plus sign (in addition to other useless situations such as multiple numbers in a row, and sequences of plusses), but not if all of them are. Also, the `g` flag does nothing with `test`.

Comment: cheers, picked up the 'g'. Seeing as the question is only specific about finding at least one '+' at the start and end of the string I thought it best to post the link and allow the user to self-teach regex for his own use.

Comment: Hi @liz_ophiuchus, well, the question said "**each** letter present must be preceded and followed by + sign.", not "there must be at least one letter preceded and followed by a + sign". Whatever. I'm all in favor of letting people work out the details by themselves, although judging from the quality of the questions it could be a lost cause.